# Как в php-unit подменять методы фреймворка?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Как можно в тесте php-unit переопределить метод фреймворка Yii2 который вызван в action?

*Пример:*

Action:

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    if (Yii::$app→user→getIsGuest()) {
```

Тест:

```php
    public function testHTML() {
        Yii::configure(Yii::$app, [
            'components' => [
                'user' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
                ]
            ],
        ]);

// Здесь подменить функцию Yii::$app→user→getIsGuest() так, чтобы она всегда возвращала true

        Yii::$app->controller = new IndexController('index', Yii::$app);
        $result = Yii::$app->controller->run('index', []);
        $this->assertInternalType('string', $result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только сначала надо создать объект, в котором будет переопределен метод, а потом его уже использовать. Для этого объект необходимо получать из контейнера.
Создаем объект, в котором переопределяем, необходимые методы и свойства.

```
    $container = new \yii\di\Container;
    $container->set('user', function ($container, $params, $config) {
        return new class () extends User
        {
            public function getIsGuest()
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
    });

    // далее тест
```

Подробнее в документации [внедрение зависимостей](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/concept-di-container)